# "defau1t:" (NOT "default:") is a valid value for label?

Tags: c++, c

Why this code compile and run fine. I have written defau1t instead of default , 1 at the place of l.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=4;
    switch(i)
    {
        case 3:
        break;
        defau1t :
        break;      
    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare arbitrary labels for `goto`.

Comment: It [doesn't compile and run without a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c6a79adc4da3830).

Comment: It compiles ... try it...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Looks like [it runs perfectly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30f751ff0e42d26a). Your compiler is just needlessly whiny.

Comment: I have no idea. I upvoted the question. It's well-written, backed up with code. And questions should *not* be downvoted on the sole grounds of being obvious.

Comment: @Bathsheba Right, but still, you can consider writing a meaningful title first. UV Q&A, it's a good one. :)

Comment: This is a sensible question. With the current complete ban on `goto`, it's to be expected that new programmers are unfamiliar with goto labels, and it's not obvious that you can put such a label in that place even if you're aware of them.

Comment: @molbdnilo: You have a point. I still think it is badly researched, but I accept it is not necessarily the fault of the asker. I still don't think it is a good question, as it apparently is not compiled with the recommended (and minimum expected) warnings enabled (see Dieter Lückings comment). In dubio pro reo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a valid name for a *label*, which you can use as a placeholder for a `goto` call. (And entering into a `switch` block via a `goto` call *is* allowable in C and C++ even if it's ill-advised).

*label* names broadly have the same rules as variable names when it comes to the characters they can contain. `defau1t` satisfies those rules.

In your case, it's benign and will be compiled out at runtime, although a good compiler will warn you that it's not used.

Comment: `a good compiler will warn you that it's not used.` +1 for that

Comment: Exactly the same. Good point.

Answer (score 8):

`defau1t :` is a valid label name, even if it is not a case label.

You could have a `goto defau1t;` somewhere else in the code.